# How do I create a table whose rows reference 1 (and only 1) of 2 existing tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

Here's my situation: I have two tables created with

```
CREATE DATABASE JsPracticeDb; 
/* Create tables corresponding to the problems, solutions to 
   problems, and ratings of problems or solutions */
CREATE TABLE Problems ( 
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    prompt_code VARCHAR(3000),
    test_func_code VARCHAR(3000),
    test_input_code VARCHAR(3000)
);
CREATE TABLE Solutions (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
   problem_id INT,
   solver_name VARCHAR(50),
   code VARCHAR(3000),
   FOREIGN KEY (problem_id) REFERENCES Problems(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
);
```

and I was thinking about creating a table for rating `Solutions`, which I wrote as

```
CREATE TABLE Ratings (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    solution_id INT,
    stars TINYINT,
    FOREIGN KEY (solution_id) REFERENCES Solutions(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

but then I realized I might actually want to have `Problems` rated as well. The "brute force" solution, as I see it, is

```
CREATE TABLE SolutionRatings (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    solution_id INT,
    stars TINYINT,
    FOREIGN KEY (solution_id) REFERENCES Solutions(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE ProblemRatings (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    problem_id INT,
    stars TINYINT,
    FOREIGN KEY (problem_id) REFERENCES Problems(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

but my programming intuition says there's a problem with the fact that I used copy-paste to write two sections of code that are almost identical. However, I can't think of any alternative solution that uses an intersection table or something like **that also allows me to do a cascade delete**. For example, I know I could do

```
CREATE TABLE RatedTables (
    id TINYINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    table_name VARCHAR(9)
);
INSERT INTO RatedTables (table_name) VALUES ('Problems','Solutions');
CREATE TABLE Ratings (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    rated_table_id TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    stars TINYINT,
    FOREIGN KEY (rated_table_id) REFERENCES RatedTables(id)
);
```

but then **how would I make it so that if a `Solution` with corresponding `Rating`s was deleted then those ratings would be too?????**

Comment: How about adding another column to the Ratings table problem_id int with the foreign key constraint FOREIGN KEY(problem_id) REFERENCES Problems(id) ON DELETE CASCADE

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options but this is a good opportunity to go back and review your db structure.

The first option is to do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE potential_link1 (
    id int primary key,
    ...
);
CREATE TABLE potential_link2 (
    id int primary key,
    ....
);
CREATE TABLE ratings (
    id int primary key,
    potential_link1 int references potential_link1(id) on delete cascade,
    potential_link2 int references potential_link2(id) on delete cascade,
    ....
    check(potential_link1 is null or potential_link2 is null),
    check(potential_link2 is not null or potential_link1 is not null)
);
```

This works but as you can see it is a bit complex.

The second possibility is that since there are clear cases where a is dependent on the union of b and c then you may think about whether you can refactor your db structure to reflect that so you only need one table to link against.

Comment: In the OPs case, they already have a FK reference with `on delete cascade` between `potential_link1` and `potential_link2`. So I don't think you'll be able to create those foreign keys in `ratings` with `on delete cascade` (because of SQL Server's over-eager cycle detector)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with two tables looking so much alike. They contain different things and you won't want to select all three-star ratings no matter whether on problems or solutions for instance - you would always work with solution ratings *or* problem ratings.

---

But to have both ratings in one table is also not wrong and can be a good idea when you want ratings to behave the same, no matter whether on problem or solution (e.g. both shall have 1 to 5 stars, both can have a comment no longer then 200 chars, ...).

This could be done by simply giving the ratings table both a problem_id and a solution_id with foreign keys on the tables and fill always one or the other. With natural keys, the same would feel even more, well, natural:

- `problem(problem_no, data)`
- `solution(problem_no, solution_no, data)`
- `rating(problem_no, solution_no, data)`

with `rating.solution_no` nullable and foreign keys on both parent tables.